# How do I map this redundant parent-child relationship using Fluent API

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, ef-fluent-api

Any suggestions on how I can double-map this parent-child relationship, where the parent has a normal 1-many relationship (which is working), but then I need a direct 1:1,0 link from the parent to a particular child.

```
Public Class Source
    <Key()>
    Public Property SourceID As Int32

    Public Property SourceFields As List(Of SourceField)

    Public Property InboundMatchKeySourceFieldID As Nullable(Of Int32)
    Public Property InboundMatchKeySourceField As SourceField
```

And

```
Public Class SourceField
    <Key()>
    Public Property SourceFieldID As Int32

    Public Property SourceID As Int32

    Public Property Source As Source
```

This is the Parent/Child Mapping (Working)

```
    modelBuilder.Entity(Of Source).HasMany(
        Function(S) S.SourceFields
    ).WithRequired(
        Function(SF) SF.Source
    ).HasForeignKey(
        Function(SF) SF.SourceID
    )
```

This is my failed attempt at an additional direct mapping (Not Working):

```
modelBuilder.Entity(Of Source
    ).HasOptional(
        Function(S) S.InboundMatchKeySourceField
    ).WithRequired(
        Function(SF) SF.Source
    )
```

This yields me the 'MetaDataException':

> Schema specified is not valid. Errors: The relationship
>   '_____.Source_InboundMatchKeySourceField' was not loaded
>   because the type '_____.SourceField' is not available.

Answer (score 0):

`.WithRequired(...)` returns a instance of `ForeignKeyNavigationPropertyConfiguration`. You need to map this relationship to a Key using the map Method, otherwise EF will try to create one for you.

so the code you are looking for is:

```
modelBuilder.Entity(Of Source
).HasOptional(
    Function(S) S.InboundMatchKeySourceField
).WithRequired(
    Function(SF) SF.Source
) _
.Map(Function (x) x.MapKey("InboundMatchKeySourceFieldID"))
```

Comment: Good suggestion, alas, I still get the same error message

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the same property `SourceField.Source` for both relationships.

There's ambiguity from Entity Framework's perspective:

- If you set `someSourceField.Source`, does that mean `someSourceField` gets added to `thatSource.SourceFields`, or `thatSource.InboundMatchKeySourceField` gets set, or both?
- What if `someSource.InboundMatchKeySourceField.Source != someSource`?

---

Perhaps you could create the second mapping without a navigation property and use validation to make sure `SourceFields.Contains(InboundMatchKeySourceField)` or `thisSource.InboundMatchKeySourceField.Source == thisSource` if needed:

```
modelBuilder.Entity(Of Source
    ).HasOptional(
        Function(S) S.InboundMatchKeySourceField
    ).WithRequired()
```